# Javascript 'delete' doesn't work inside iteration loop

Tags: javascript

I'm a C/C++/Java programmer working with JavaScript.

I'm trying to write a function that will delete all properties of an object 'obj'. I've read the posting on "[How to quickly clear a Javascript Object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684575/how-to-quickly-clear-a-javascript-object)" and saw that there are two answers: (1) creating a new 'obj' (which I don't want to do because my code is a high-performance program running in a mobile browser, and I want to minimize garbage collection); and (2) iterating over the properties of an object in a loop and deleting the properties. This latter approach doesn't work in Chrome 12.

Consider the following code:

```
var foo = {};
foo['baz'] = 'bar';
console.log("1. foo.baz = " + foo.baz);

delete foo.baz;
console.log("2. foo.baz = " + foo.baz);

foo['baz'] = 'bar';
console.log("3. foo.baz = " + foo.baz);

for (prop in foo)
{
    if (foo.hasOwnProperty(prop))
    {
        console.log("deleting property " + prop);
        delete foo.prop;
    }
}
console.log("4. foo.baz = " + foo.baz);
```

This produces the following result in my console on Chrome 12:

```
1. foo.baz = bar
2. foo.baz = undefined
3. foo.baz = bar
deleting property baz
4. foo.baz = bar
```

Why doesn't foo.baz get deleted inside the loop?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You lookup the `key` in the wrong way. You need to use the *bracket notation*:

```
delete foo[ prop ];
```

However, you don't need to loop over every property within an object. It's just fine to `null` the object reference itself. The garbage collector will take care of you.

```
foo = null; // done
```

Talking of high performance, that is the way you want to do.

Comment: (1) I was under the impression that the property notation foo.prop and foo[prop] were equivalent, for example as mentioned in http://www.jibbering.com/faq/faq_notes/square_brackets.html. (2) Why does "delete foo.baz" work in my example? (3) As I mentioned, I want to minimize garbage collection since I'm working on a mobile browser.

Comment: `foo.prop` is equivalent to `foo["prop"]`.  see the difference?  If you want to dynamically pull a property from `foo`, you need to use `foo[prop]`.

Comment: @stackoverflowuser2010: I'd put some more faith into the GC. If you don't create a ton of objects on each click, you should be fine. Explicitly deleting all properties and then adding new ones may very well take longer than just creating a new one and leaving the old one to the GC!

Comment: @digitalbath: Then the code in this posting is incorrect, right? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/684575/how-to-quickly-clear-a-javascript-object

Comment: @stackoverflowuser2010: trying to clear/remove used memory with javascript ist just unnesessary. I don't thing this can possibly be faster than letting the GC do the job. If you got any source for that, let me know.

Answer (score 3):

This line `delete foo.prop` is incorrect. `foo` has no property named `prop` in this case. Using brackets `delete foo[prop]`.

Comment: Hmm. I wonder why this was downvoted. I don't see anything wrong with it in particular.

Comment: I wondered myself. I think someone was jealous of my quick answer. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Because `foo.prop` never was defined to delete. You need to delete it like this:

```
delete foo[prop];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
delete foo[prop];
```

HTH