# Clear variables Adobe Analytics (DTM)

Tags: javascript, adobe, analytics, adobe-analytics

On DTM, in every pageViews and events I've included these code lines to clear variables in 'Javascript / Third Party Script' box.

```
var s = _satellite.getToolsByType('sc')[0].getS();
s.clearVars();
```

I'm having problems trying to clear variables in the following case:
When there's an onclick event that redirect to another page, this code always fails and copy its variables(event variables) in the pageView hit.

I enroll an picture with an example. 
[Variables copied among hits](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9GxU.jpg)

How can I solve this problem?
Thank you!

Comment: Are those variables set on the next page?

Comment: To solve this issue, see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28048759/when-and-how-to-use-s-clearvars-in-omniture/46960014#46960014

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an event-based rule to capture the onClick event, DTM will automatically set linkTrackVars and linkTrackEvents to "None". This should prevent the previous page view events from cascading to the next call.

However, if you're sending page view data (s.tl()) with the onClick, then yes, your previous events could be included.

I would suggest using event-based rules for the onClick events if possible so only your specific events are set.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function ClearVars() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        s['prop' + i] = '';
        s['eVar' + i] = '';
        if (i <= 5)
            s['hier' + i] = '';
    }
    s.list2 = '';
    s.list1 = '';
    svarArr = ['pageName', 'channel', 'products', 'events', 'campaign', 'purchaseID', 'state', 'zip', 'server', 'linkName'];
    for (var i = 0; i < svarArr.length; i++) {
        s[svarArr[i]] = '';
    }
}

ClearVars();
```