# How to completely clear property values and references of a javascript object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, design-patterns, coffeescript

I made a simple game yesterday in javascript using coffeescript. The bulk of the game runs through a `game` object which is instantiated after the user submits a form on the page. The form contains variables and options for the game they want to play.

Everything works fine during the game, but when the game is over I have the form appear again and if the user submits the form a second time its supposed to call the same function and overwrite the old `game` variable with a new instance of the `game` object, but what I've noticed is that its not resetting all the existing variables and paramaters set by the original game object.

Is there any way to fully remove the old object and its parameter when a new one is instantiated?

Here is My object being declared as a 'class' in coffeescript.

```
window.Game   = class Game

  constructor: (options) ->
    players  = options[0] ? '1'
    p1 =  p2 = false
    @player1 = new Player(options[1] ? 'X', p1 )
    @player2 = new Player(options[2] ? 'O', p2 )
    @cells   = ($ "section#board .cell")
    @cells.each ->
      $(@).text(" ")
      $(@).removeClass('score')
    @currentPlayer = @player1
    @availableMoves = 9
    ($ 'section#board div.cell').bind
      click:      @.makeMove
      mouseleave: @.resetCell

    setTimeout(@.computerMove(@currentPlayer), 1000) if parseInt(players) is 0
```

I'm calling this after form submit through this function.

```
($ '#gameOptions').submit (event) ->
  event.target.checkValidity()
  event.preventDefault()
  game = new Game [($ '#player-count') .val(), 
                   ($ '#player-1-type').val(),
                   ($ '#player-2-type').val()]
```

Even when adding a call do `delete game` before re-instantiating the game object. The ghost variables persist. I posted in coffeescipt for brevity and to increase readability.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to quickly clear a Javascript Object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/684575/how-to-quickly-clear-a-javascript-object)

Comment: possible dup http://stackoverflow.com/questions/742623/deleting-objects-in-javascript

Comment: this has been asked plenty of times here. just search fro delete object javascript.

Comment: Sounds like you're not doing your construction/instantiation properly. Whatever variables you're leaving out, just override them on the form submission.

Comment: I've read all those posts and searched delete objects in javascript. They dont touch on exactly what I'm getting at here. I'll add some code to try and clear up the question a little bit.

Comment: If the form submission you are talking about was a non-Ajax request then the entire page would be refreshed and that would automatically clear _everything_ from the previous run.

Comment: @nnnnnn Oh, thats a good idea. I may just try that. I could just move the highscores to browser cache. (No server side for this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `delete game` will not remove the object, only the reference.  The problem is that references to the old variable are persisting somewhere.  There might be others, but at the very least this part of the constructor is giving you problems:

```
  ($ 'section#board div.cell').bind
    click:      @.makeMove
    mouseleave: @.resetCell
```

JQuery is allowing you to bind multiple functions to the same event; in this case, both the old and new functions, and the old ones are holding the reference to the old object.  In order to fix this, you should unbind in the form submission function:

```
($ 'section#board div.cell').unbind()
```

Comment: That actually did help with a parameter relating to player movement. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: @JustinHerrick Are there still problems?  If so, we'll probably need more info.

Comment: The two issues I'm having is that after the first game is finished (and every game afterwords) the starting player is not set to player 1, its almost consistently set to player2 and the existing player variables seem to be holding on to the old variables that they are human.... 

I'm starting to think that I may need to manually delete (dereference) those objects when the game ends

Comment: @JustinHerrick The only way that would happen is if the `Game` object was actually the old one.  How are you distributing the `Game` object among various functions?

Comment: Its fairly self contained. You can view all the source on here https://github.com/jah2488/tic-tac-coffee/blob/master/js/script.coffee

After what you see above. I simply call object methods under game to validate user moves and handle the active player. etc.

Comment: @JustinHerrick From your github, the line `($ 'section#board div.cells').off()` isn't working because the selector should be `section#board div.cell`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8565/discussion-between-aaron-dufour-and-justin-herrick)

Comment: That fixed it Actually. Thanks so much for your help Aaron.