# Reset object to empty object keeping references intact in non-linear time

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have `obj1` with only enumerable properties:

```
var obj1 = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 };
```

I then create `obj2` which holds a reference to `obj1`:

```
var obj2 = obj1;
obj1 === obj2; // true
```

At some point, I want to reset `obj1` to an empty object:

```
for (key in obj1) {
  delete obj1[key];
}
obj1 === obj2; // true
```

But I'd like to avoid having to iterater over all the properties:

```
obj1 = {};
obj1 === obj2; // false (this obviously doesn't work)
```

Is there another solution?

Comment: Almost a dupe of [How to quickly clear a Javascript Object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/684575/how-to-quickly-clear-a-javascript-object)

Comment: Yeah, but the constraint that I retain reference is important here.

Comment: You can keep the delete code short using: `Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key){delete obj[key]})`. This deletes only enumerable, deletable properties. A for..in loop must include a *hasOwnProperty* test.

Comment: Create a helper function and do `empty(obj1);`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have flexibility on the data model, then store the actual properties in a child object:

```
var obj1 = {theData: { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3} };
```

then you can reset the properties with `obj1.theData = {}`.

Of course, that implies that access to any property will incur an additional "hop", so depending on how often you access the data (read or write it) vs. reset the object, you might be better off keeping the `delete` loop.

Other than that, I don't believe you can reset an object like you can an Array (via `a.length=0`).

Comment: Noting that setting an array's length to zero only deletes numeric properties, it doesn't delete others. ;-)