# When will .bind() run?

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

I'm trying to schedule a bunch of tasks to run on time intervals using changing config data as input:

```
let configData = initConfig();  // Initialize configuration data from file

setInterval(taskA.bind(null, configData), TASK_A_WAIT);  // Task using config data

setInterval(taskB.bind(null, configData), TASK_B_WAIT);  // Task using config data

setInterval(taskC.bind(null, configData), TASK_C_WAIT);  // Task using config data

setInterval(refreshConfig.bind(null, (error, result) => {    // Update config data
    if (error) handleError(error);
    else configData = result;
}), CONFIG_REFRESH_WAIT);
```

The goal is for the configuration data to update on interval using the last `setInterval()`, so that the first three `setInterval()`'s always have the latest data to work with. But will it work?

In the semantics of javascript, will the above actually bind the function to the latest `configData` object anew with every interval? When do binds happen in such a scenario?

Comment: No, because `configData = result` overwrites the reference, not the value. The tasks will still be bound to the old reference.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts So if I understand correctly, the binds will happen once, but because binds are by reference and the values at the appropriate references are updated with each pass of the last `setInterval()` refreshing the config data, the values for `configData` fed into the three tasks will indeed be up-to-date with every interval?

Comment: binds are by value... sort of. The problem is your `configData`'s reference is changing, but the `.bind()` will hold onto the old reference.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts So if `configData` is an object, because the references will change, it won't work. But if `configData` is not an object, it will work? Mind writing up an answer so I can upvote it?

Comment: It does not matter what `configData` is, it will not work.

Answer (score 3):

Since `bind()` isn't wrapped in another function, it is synchronously executed in-place.

Task functions are bound to original `configData`. If it's reassigned with `configData = result`, this doesn't affect bound functions.

Task functions should be wrapped with functions to get reassigned `configData`:

```
setInterval(() => { taskA(configData) }, TASK_A_WAIT)
```

Another option that will work with `bind` is to preserve same reference for `configData` object, this will work only if initial `configData` is an object:

```
setInterval(refreshConfig.bind(null, (error, result) => {
  ... 
  Object.assign(configData, result);
}), CONFIG_REFRESH_WAIT);
```

If there's a chance that `configData` already has properties that possibly won't be overridden, it should be [cleared](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684575/how-to-quickly-clear-a-javascript-object) first.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the tasks to continue referring to the live version of `configData`, you should pass an anonymous wrapper function to each of the calls for `setInterval()` like this, which scopes the symbolic variable reference rather than binding the original object reference to each function:

```
let configData = initConfig();  // Initialize configuration data from file

setInterval(() => taskA(configData), TASK_A_WAIT);  // Task using config data

setInterval(() => taskB(configData), TASK_B_WAIT);  // Task using config data

setInterval(() => taskC(configData), TASK_C_WAIT);  // Task using config data

setInterval(refreshConfig.bind(null, (error, result) => {    // Update config data
    if (error) handleError(error);
    else configData = result;
}), CONFIG_REFRESH_WAIT);
```

Alternatively, if you don't want the reference to change, and you know that the configuration's structure will never change, you might prefer to make `configData` a `const` reference and use `Object.assign()` to do a shallow copy of `result`'s keys, overwriting each key in `configData` with the new values in `result`:

```
const configData = initConfig();  // Initialize configuration data from file

setInterval(taskA.bind(null, configData), TASK_A_WAIT);  // Task using config data

setInterval(taskB.bind(null, configData), TASK_B_WAIT);  // Task using config data

setInterval(taskC.bind(null, configData), TASK_C_WAIT);  // Task using config data

setInterval(refreshConfig.bind(null, (error, result) => {    // Update config data
    if (error) handleError(error);
    else Object.assign(configData, result);
}), CONFIG_REFRESH_WAIT);
```

Comment: Hah. Didn't look above to make sure that someone else not doing the same thing, too. No wonder, there are not so many options for this to work.

Comment: There's actually something really interesting in here that I didn't know about javascript. The `const` keyword can be used to make constant references, with mutable values?