# What is the best way to clear the properties of an object in Vuex state

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuex

Suppose you have this object in the `state` of the Vuex store:

```js
const state = {
  profile: {
   name: "Bob",
   jobTitle: 'Baker',
   age: 38,
  }
}
```

In the Vue.js template you can access this object with a `computed` property like this:

```html
<template>
    <p>Welcome {{ profile.name }}</p>
</template>
```

This works fine but requires the properties to be defined upfront. And when there is no logged on user each property of `profile` needs to be set to an empty string. Because when we set `state.profile = null` the Vue template will complain that it can't find the property `name` anymore.

What is the best way to handle a case like this? Would we need to [iterate the object properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684575/how-to-quickly-clear-a-javascript-object) and set them all to a blank string or is there a better way of handling this?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a factory method that returns an empty `profile` object/model to initialize your state. Then you add a `reset` action to your VUEX store that re-initializes your `profile` state whenever you need it.

Look at [THIS](https://medium.com/@Taha_Shashtari/reset-vuex-module-state-like-a-pro-1acb7f8d9e21) article. This explains the above in more detail.

Comment: Thank you, that is some pretty clever stuff! The only disadvantage that I see is with regards to readability. You can't simply open the `state.js` file and see the properties.

Comment: You're not restricted to putting everything in one file if that's what you mean. You could separate your factory methods out in their own files. There's also a possibility to make use of VUEX Modules: https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/modules.html. That allows you to split-up your VUEX store into different (feature related) sections.

Comment: You're right! I'm still learning and didn't see it at first. But yes, I think this is the correct answer. Thanks again for the great tip :)