# vue 3 reactivity shorthand?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

So I have an Object that is empty and after the user submits the value, it is saved.

```
 let state = reactive({
      id: '',
      name: '',
      status: 0,
    }
```

after the submit, I would like to save my values.

```
  onResult(() => {
        state.id = '1'
        state.name = 'Name'
        state.status = 1
      })
```

I would like to swap the complete object like I would do it in a ref, like:

```
state.value = {
  id: '1,
  name: 'Name',
  state: 1
};
```

Is there any shorthand when using reactive?

Answer (score 1):

This is not specific to reactive objects and would require to [clear an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684575/how-to-quickly-clear-a-javascript-object), which is inefficient.

This is the case for a ref. It can be unwrapped in a script if needed to skip value access:

```
const stateRef = ref({...})
const stateObj = shallowReadonly(stateRef);
```